# Keyboard shortcut to paste to active window in GNOME (Fedora)

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

What I'd like to achieve is to be able to press a button (F9 in this case) and for a specific string to be "pasted" into the active window. (It's to save typing a very long password - I know, I'm doing it wrong but the devices in question do not support PKI).

I've tried using xhotkeys, this gives me the ability to execute an arbitrary command on a specific keystroke however I don't seem to be able to find any way to make it "paste" into the active window.

I'm positive there is a way - any help appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the hint by @thrig this is now solved!

Turns out "pasting" wasn't really necessary - xdotool provides a "type" function which allows me to send some keystrokes to the active window and also a "key" function allowing me to submit the input.
Final gotcha was that you have to add a slight delay for this to work smothly (https://askubuntu.com/questions/212154/create-a-custom-shortcut-that-types-clipboard-contents)

Final solution was to create a custom shortcut (via gnome) that runs the following custom command:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.4; xdotool type "secret"; xdotool key Return'
```